# How to check if strings in an array contains two or more strings from a two-dimensional array?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, ecmascript-6

What am I ultimately trying to do?

**Check news article JSONs for the country keywords of two or more countries, and return those articles.**

This is a little bit complicated (at least for me), so please bear with me.

I am currently receiving news article JSONs from an API.  I am successfully using Underscore _.map to grab the description key value of each object.  It is these values that I will be iterating over for keywords:

```
let combinedBing = this.bingWorldJSON.value.concat(this.bingPoliticsJSON.value);
let bingArray = _.map(combinedBing, 'description');
```

I am checking those descriptions for keywords I might have in another (dynamic) array, called event. I am using the .map method for this. Example:

```
  let event = ["United States", "Russia"]
  let result =  event.map(function(word){
        return newArray.filter(function(article){
        // console.log(article);
        return article.toString().indexOf(word) > -1;
      });
    });
```

This returns a two-dimensional array, like this:

```
[Array(4), Array(0)]
0:Array(4)
0:"No sign probes into Russia, Trump campaign will die down"
1:"Russian Hackers Who Targeted Clinton Appear to Attack France’s Macron"
2:"Senate Russia investigation to add 2 staffers"
3:"Former Trump adviser Flynn likely broke law with Russia trip: lawmakers"
length:4
__proto__:Array(0)
1:Array(0)
length:2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

However, I don't just want to use the words in the event array, as it is very limiting.  Why?  Because the news articles that are returned don't always use the strict country names, but often have semantic equivalents (i.e. "U.S." instead of "United States", or "Russia's" instead of "Russia").

Because my 'event' array is created dynamically (and I can't change the strict country names in that array), I am pushing a hardcoded array of equivalent keywords to another array (if that country is present in 'event').  Therefore, if my 'event' has

```
["United States, "Russia"]
```

I will also be creating a two-dimensional array, like this:

```
[["United States", "U.S.", "US", "America"], ["Russia", "Russian", "Putin", "Moscow"]]
```

Instead of using event.map (as successfully done above), I am trying to figure out how to map the keywords of each array (in the 2-d array) against the articles I am returning.  And not just that, but return the articles that include the keywords from two or more countries.  For instance, if an article has the keywords "U.S." and "Moscow", it would return that article, and any other article that contained a combination of keywords of those two countries.

I know this might seem slightly convoluted.  But because there is no keyword search in these API's I'm using, I am trying to do it manually.

I really appreciate the patience it took to read this!  Thank you for any help or ideas on how to approach this.

Comment: How about merging your event and keyword arrays into a third array and use the map function with that new array?

Comment: I would, but I don't think .map works on multidimensional arrays.  And it also wouldn't return articles with keywords of multiple countries.  I don't think.

Comment: flatten the array.  make a single 1-dimentional array:  `["United States, "Russia", "U.S.", "US", "America", "Russian", "Putin", "Moscow"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get only those articles that mention at least two different countries (or one of their alternative words), then:

```js
const bingArray = [
    "No sign probes into Russia, Trump campaign will die down",
    "Russian Hackers Who Targeted Clinton Appear to Attack France’s Macron",
    "Senate Russia investigation to add 2 staffers",
    "Former Trump adviser Flynn likely broke law with Russia trip: lawmakers",
    'Big meeting in Moscow tomorrow',
    'Russia has U.S. ambassy closed',
    'Did Putin influence the United States elections?',
];

const event = [["United States", "U.S.", "US", "America"], 
               ["Russia", "Russian", "Putin", "Moscow"]];

const matches = bingArray.filter( 
    article => event.filter( 
        words => words.find( 
            word => article.includes(word) 
        ) 
    ).length > 1
);

console.log('articles mentioning at least 2 countries:');
console.log(matches);
```

If you want that only articles are included that match with *all* entries of *event*, not just 2, then use `every`:

```js
const bingArray = [
    "No sign probes into Russia, Trump campaign will die down",
    "Russian Hackers Who Targeted Clinton Appear to Attack France’s Macron",
    "Senate Russia investigation to add 2 staffers",
    "Former Trump adviser Flynn likely broke law with Russia trip: lawmakers",
    'Big meeting in Moscow tomorrow',
    'Russia has U.S. ambassy closed',
    'Did Putin influence the United States elections?',
];

const event = [["United States", "U.S.", "US", "America"], 
               ["Russia", "Russian", "Putin", "Moscow"]];

const matches = bingArray.filter( 
    article => event.every( 
        words => words.find( 
            word => article.includes(word) 
        ) 
    )
);

console.log('articles mentioning all listed countries:');
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: You managed to make what I thought was insanely difficult seem very easy.  lol.  It works.  I learned from you today - thanks a lot...

Comment: If I wanted to adjust it to ensure that at least one word from each inner array was included, would I change the length?

Comment: Then you would use `every(...)` instead of `filter(...).length > 1`. I added a snippet to my answer for that.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find?v=example) if it's multi-dimensional array

```js
let newArray = ["No sign probes into Moscow, Trump (America) campaign will die down", "Russian Hackers Who Targeted Clinton Appear to Attack France’s Macron", "Senate U.S.(United States) investigation to add 2 staffers", "Putin foo bar", "US test"];

let event = [["United States", "U.S.", "US", "America"], ["Russia", "Russian", "Putin", "Moscow"]]
let result = event.map(words => newArray.filter(article => words.find(word => article.toString().indexOf(word) > -1)));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only care about the events containing a *single* keyword from the array of eventKeywords, the following works

```
const events = [
  "No sign probes into Russia, Trump campaign will die down",
  "Russian Hackers Who Targeted Clinton Appear to Attack France’s Macron",
  "Senate Russia investigation to add 2 staffers",
  "Former Trump adviser Flynn likely broke law with Russia trip: lawmakers",
]
const eventKeywords = [["United States", "U.S.", "US", "America", "Trump"], ["Russia", "Russian", "Putin", "Moscow"]]

const myDesiredEvents = events.filter(ev => {
  return eventKeywords.filter(keywords => {
    return keywords.filter(k => ev.toString().indexOf(k) > -1).length > 0
  }).length > 0
})

// myDesiredEvents == [
//  "No sign probes into Russia, Trump campaign will die down",
//  "Russian Hackers Who Targeted Clinton Appear to Attack France’s Macron",
//  "Senate Russia investigation to add 2 staffers",
//  "Former Trump adviser Flynn likely broke law with Russia trip: lawmakers",
//]
```

If you need the events to contain a minimum of 2 *different sets* of keywords, use the following (just changed `.length >= 2` at the end)

```
const events = [
  "No sign probes into Russia, Trump campaign will die down",
  "Russian Hackers Who Targeted Clinton Appear to Attack France’s Macron",
  "Senate Russia investigation to add 2 staffers",
  "Former Trump adviser Flynn likely broke law with Russia trip: lawmakers",
]
const eventKeywords = [["United States", "U.S.", "US", "America", "Trump"], ["Russia", "Russian", "Putin", "Moscow"]]

const myDesiredEvents = events.filter(ev => {
  return eventKeywords.filter(keywords => {
    return keywords.filter(k => ev.toString().indexOf(k) > -1).length > 0
  }).length >= 2
})

// myDesiredEvents == [
//  "No sign probes into Russia, Trump campaign will die down",
//  "Former Trump adviser Flynn likely broke law with Russia trip: lawmakers"
//  ]
```

EDIT to add a flatten option which is a little less code and a little cleaner

If you only need a single match in your 2-dimensional array of keywords, if you flatten your 2 dimensional array, it turns it into a single array of keywords to check

```
const events = [
  "No sign probes into Russia, Trump campaign will die down",
  "Russian Hackers Who Targeted Clinton Appear to Attack France’s Macron",
  "Senate Russia investigation to add 2 staffers",
  "Former Trump adviser Flynn likely broke law with Russia trip: lawmakers",
]
const eventKeywords = [["United States", "U.S.", "US", "America", "Trump"], ["Russia", "Russian", "Putin", "Moscow"]]
const flattenedEventKeywords = [].concat.apply([], eventKeywords)
// flattenedEventKeywords == ["United States", "U.S.", "US", "America", "Trump", "Russia", "Russian", "Putin", "Moscow"]

const myDesiredEvents = events.filter(ev => {
  return flattenedEventKeywords.filter(keywords => {
    return ev.toString().indexOf(keywords) > -1
  }).length > 0
})

// myDesiredEvents == [
//  "No sign probes into Russia, Trump campaign will die down",
//  "Russian Hackers Who Targeted Clinton Appear to Attack France’s Macron",
//  "Senate Russia investigation to add 2 staffers",
//  "Former Trump adviser Flynn likely broke law with Russia trip: lawmakers",
//]
```